# Close express server when client emits to server with Socket.io

Tags: express, socket.io

Goal: close server when client emits message.
I can confirm client sends response as it logs: 'hit server

Server code for express is:

```
io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  console.log('this is connected');
  socket.on('message', function(data){
    console.log('hit server');
    server.close();
  })

});

io.on('error', function() {
  console.log('there is an error');
})

server.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('listen on *:3000');
});
```

Comment: `server.close()` will stop a nodejs server from accepting any new connections.  It does not kill existing connections.  If you want to kill existing connections, then you have to iterate through the existing connections and close them individually.  Or, you can call `process.exit()` and that will shut down everything.

Comment: What problem are you actually trying to solve here?  Why are you wanting to do this?

Comment: The answer helps.  I activate a server every night at midnight and it sends a socket message to a client in an Adobe program.   That triggers it to run some code.  And then I need the server to completely shut off so it can run again the next day.  If it doesn't shut down it won't run as it attempts to activate the server again and it's already active.  @jfriend00

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To stop an Express server that you're using socket.io with, you first call:

```
server.close();
```

That stops it from accepting new http connections.  You can then iterate existing socket.io connections and close each of them:

```
const sockets = await io.fetchSockets();
for (let socket of sockets) {
    socket.disconnect(true);
}
```

This could, in theory, leave a few regular http connections that are still in process, but will eventually complete or timeout.

```
server.getConnections(callback)
```

will tell you if there are any more outstanding connections or not.

---

If you just want to shut everything down, including your app, you can call:

```
process.exit()
```